# How we can Integrate HMS Kit in Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Patch 1)?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Patch 1) released on February 4, 2022

Answer (score 2):

Here I am going to discuss you about HMS Kit Integration in Android Studio new version **Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Patch 1)**  which is released on **February 4, 2022**. There are some changes in project level **build.gradle** file and **settings.gradle**. So I am sharing a temporary solution to integrate HMS Kits here.

**1) In root build.gradle**

There are some changes in root level **build.gradle** file in new version.

[image]

**buildscript** removed here in new version,  where we add Add the AppGallery Connect plugin.

So to integrate HMS Kits  add buildscript as given

[image]
Note : No need to configure the Maven repository address in root level **build.gradle**

**2) settings.gradle**

Few changes are there in **settings.gradle**. We can find **pluginManagement** and **dependencyResolutionManagement** there. Add maven url in both sections as mentioned in below image.

[image]

**3) App level build.gradle**

No other changes in App level **build.gradle** file. You can add a build dependency in the dependencies block and can add the AppGallery Connect plugin configuration.

**That's it.**

I know it is a temporary solution, but you can use it till we get a permanent solution.

Thank you.